# Extracting an expression from the body of a response, and using it for the next post in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test that I have created that does a post and then runs a secondary post with a string from the first response. I have a regular expression extractor that is getting the information from the response correctly, but when I try to call it in the next post it returns a value of 0. My question is: How do I store this value and reference it correctly in the second post?

Regular Expression Extractor:

[image]

Response text:

> response_code=2 response_code_text=Missing required request field:
>   Order ID. time_stamp=1479849486545 retry_recommended=false
>   secondary_response_code=0 order_id=356005935614233
>   capture_reference_id=1 iso_code= bank_approval_code=
>   bank_transaction_id= batch_id= avs_code=
>   credit_card_verification_response= reference_id=1 bin=
>   retrieval_reference_number= payer_identifier= system_trace_number=
>   captured_amount=0.00 emv_data= bank_response_code=

RegExp Tester:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Variable reference call in second post:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue, I simply needed to change the Match No to "1". Then I was able to pass the order_id into the next post.